# Grails Validation Not Working After Upgrade

Tags: validation, grails, constraints, grails-orm

I am in the process of upgrading my Grails 1.3.7 app to 2.0.3 and I have fixed most issues. However, I have code that used to work that creates a user and saves them to the database. The code should NOT pass validation as I am reusing a username that is already taken and there is a unique constraint on username. `.validate()` returns true, but then the code actually bombs when `user.save()` is called with a MySql unique constraint error.

Should throw an error:

```
def submitSignup = {
        def user = new User(params)

        user.validate()
        if (!user.hasErrors()) {
            ...
            // This line bombs with the MySql unique constraint I would have expected .validate() to get
            user.save()
        }
}
```

In User.groovy:

```
static constraints = {
    username(blank: false, unique: true);
    ...
}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: I am also upgrading to the Spring Security plugin from Acegi. I don't think this would be relevant, but I figured I would mention it.

I put up a sample that suffers from the problem at: https://github.com/skazzaks/Grails-Unique-Test  This makes it definitely look like a bug.

Comment: Is this failing for you in a test or how did you come across this issue?  I setup a simple unit test and the unique constraint is working properly for me.

Comment: @JarredOlson This is failing when I ran the application and tried to submit a new User (that has the username already taken). This works correctly on the 1.3.7 version that I have in production. I am not sure how to account for the disparity.

Comment: I was experiencing a somewhat related validation issue after having added the unique constraint to a grails application while it was running. validate() didn't complain about values that where not unique. It helped to clean, manually delete the target directory and compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a bug due to the fact that my Domain classes are in `src/groovy`.

Answer (score 4):

I was experiencing a similar weird validation issue a couple of days ago while upgrading from 1.3.7 to 2.0.3.

What did the trick for me was a manual clearing of my target dir. Apparently recompiling of all the classes put the application back on track.

Don't know if it will work in your case though, but might be worth a try.

Comment: I was experiencing a somewhat related validation issue after having added the unique constraint to a grails application while it was running. validate() didn't complain about values that where not unique. It helped to clean, manually delete the target directory and compile.